# I need help to find this component

Tags: pcb-design, identification, ferrite-bead

I found these at the entrance of an analog input, so I think these are ferrite beads with a metal ground case but I need the part number. I searched several component websites but I couldn't figure it out (Mouser, Digikey, Farnell). I checked the manual and it doesn't have a schematic or BOM.

I have found that the case is connected to ground with a series resistance of 0.4 ohm. The inductance is 6uH and the IC on the right is an AD7190.

[image][image]

Comment: Also measure capacitance from center lead to case and add that information to your question.

Comment: Voting to close because questions seeking recommendations for specific components or where to find them is off-topic for this site. Any answers may become inaccurate as parts become obsolete, pages move, companies die, etc.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I think this is close to off-topic, but the identification of an odd component may still be on topic.

Comment: is this for a battery cell balancer?

Comment: these are smaller but what specs are you requiring? https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/tdk-corporation/ACH3218-223-TD01/445-2097-2-ND/600396 https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/filters/feed-through-capacitors/845?k=TDK%20yff&pageSize=

Comment: I'd questions are on-topic, just because the OP mentioned that they did a search on a distributor doesn't mean that this is a shopping question

Comment: If you want people to identify a component for you (a part number, even!), then provide them with sharper photos. The second picture, in particular, is close to useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is some kind of EMI feedthru filter with capacitance to ground, series inductance and series resistance.

RLC at various frequencies might give more clues.

Considering they seem to come in pairs, I am surprised they do not have CM SMD chokes.   But what about the SOT between pairs?  This is just a 4 channel single-ended ADC. What cable lengths are connected to inputs?

> I'm not sure you want a single ended 10A feedthru (gnd ) filter for an ADC high impedance input that may have large CM noise.  Yet @JohnD was successful in finding specs.

Answer (score 3):

These look like feed-through EMI filters.  You can find these or similar parts here:

[Feed-through filters](http://www.maruwa-g.com/e/products/electronic-parts/000354.html) 
or another source [here](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1388/0900766b813885c3.pdf)

The equivalent circuit looks like this:
[image]

You can use an LCR bridge to measure the approximate values of inductance and capacitance if you want to select a similar part.  They do include a lossy ferrite for some AC resistance.

Comment: I bought much bigger EMI filters ... these look quite easy to be fit in an enclosure or on a PCB.

Comment: thanks thats the answer what i am searching for last few days it really helps :)